# how to stop printing after finished in printer job java

Tags: java, printing

i have the problem in my printer Job ..
i was set my script and set the paper size, but the printer always scrolling after finish printing  ..
i use epson LX-300+II
in my epson LX-300, LX-310, and LX-800 the printing it's running normaly and printer automatic stop when finish printing, but in my epson LX-300+II the printer always scrolling after finish printing.
i don't know why, and i use the same script for printing ..
here is my script for set custom paper size :

```
public void setPrinter(String textParam, String spesialWords, int gotoX2) {

    try {
        String destination = "";
        boolean printToDoc = true;
        PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        //boolean printDialog = pj.printDialog();
        System.out.println("--------------------");

        //PageFormat pf = pj.getPageFormat(null);
        PageFormat pf = pj.defaultPage();
        Paper paper = pf.getPaper();

        double cm = 72.0 / 2.54;
        if (!destination.equalsIgnoreCase("document.pdf")) {
            if (destination.equalsIgnoreCase("printer")) {
                paper.setSize(26 * cm, 7 * cm);
            }
        }
                paper.setSize(23 * cm, 7 * cm);
        double getHeight = 7 * cm;
        double getWidth = 23 * cm;
        double margin = 0.0; // half inch

        paper.setImageableArea(margin, margin, paper.getWidth(), paper.getHeight());
        pf.setPaper(paper);
        System.out.println("==========================================");
        System.out.println("paper height : "+getHeight);
        System.out.println("paper width : "+getWidth);

        PrintRequestAttributeSet attr_set = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        if (destination.equalsIgnoreCase("document.pdf")) {
            PrintService defaultPrintService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
            DocPrintJob printerJob = defaultPrintService.createPrintJob();
            File pdfFile = new File(destination);
            SimpleDoc simpleDoc = new SimpleDoc(pdfFile.toURL(), DocFlavor.URL.AUTOSENSE, null);
            try {
                printerJob.print(simpleDoc, null);
            } catch (PrintException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Printing2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        } else if (destination.equalsIgnoreCase("document.ps")) {
            try {
                if (textParam.toLowerCase().contains("post")) {
                    destination = "post_"+destination;
                } else if (textParam.toLowerCase().contains("non")) {
                    destination = "non_"+destination;
                } else if (textParam.toLowerCase().contains("token")) {
                    destination = "pre_"+destination;
                }

                attr_set.add(new Destination(new java.net.URI("file:" + destination)));
            } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Printing2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        PrinterResolution pr = new PrinterResolution(120, 144, PrinterResolution.DPI);
        attr_set.add(pr);

        pj.setPrintable(new MyPrintable(textParam, spesialWords, gotoX2), pf);
        if (!destination.equalsIgnoreCase("document.pdf")) {

            try {
                //System.out.println("ini print");
                if (destination.equalsIgnoreCase("xps")) {
                    pj.print();
                } else {
                    pj.print(attr_set);
                }
            } catch (PrinterException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Gagal mencetak struk, Silahkan lihat pengaturan printer anda");
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        //System.out.println("testing cuuy");
        Logger.getLogger(Printing2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve my problem with :
change my driver printer of lx-300+II to lx-800
i don't know why.
but it's working perfectly